# Xcode: Load native back icon as leftBarButtonItem in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I'm using the newest version of `Xcode` and `Swift`.

I set the back button in my navigation bar as follows:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack(_:)))
```

This shows the word `Back` in the upper left corner.

Is there a way to show the Apple native back button arrow without any text instead?

Or, do I have to load a custom back icon myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use image like below.

```
let btnBack = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back"), 
                              style: .plain, 
                              target: navigationController, 
                              action: #selector(UINavigationController.popViewController(animated:)))

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack

navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

Comment: Got it, I have to load a custom image. Isn't it possible to load the Apple native back arrow?

Comment: Do you have the "Back" image in your asset?

Comment: Currently not. But I can search for any back arrow and load this im my assets. No problem. I thought it's possible to access Apples native back arrow.

Comment: It is only possible if the master class does not have a title, and you push the details page through navigation controller. Master also should be under navigation controller